# search elements by class and put id on each element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class = "myClass"></div>
<div class = "myClass"></div>
<div class = "myClass"></div>
<div class = "myClass"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here i have a set of divs with class "myClass"..how can i put each one of them a specific id using jquery?

Here's what i wanted. i can't edit the html file..that's why i wanted to use jquery to add ids.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class = "myClass" id = "1"></div>
<div class = "myClass" id = "2"></div>
<div class = "myClass" id = "3"></div>
<div class = "myClass" id = "4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = 0;
$('.myClass').each(function() {
 i++;
 $(this).attr('id', i); });
```

[Liveweave](http://liveweave.com/tmnClo)

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). Try this:

```
$("div.myClass").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr("id",i+1);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/pZv79/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('.myClass').uniqueId();
```

This will add Id to all elements of myClass class. Id will start with "ui-id-"
Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/10/

Refer: [uniqueId()](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 1;
$(".myClass").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("id", count);
  count++;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn6dV/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** to itearate over the elements with class `myClass` and **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to set the `id` of targeted elements:

```
$('div.myClass').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id',i+1);    
});
```

Also, `id` start with number is an invalid HTML, you should do something like:

```
$('div.myClass').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id','div' + (i+1));    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BT9E3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
$('.myClass').each(function() {

 $(this).attr('id', i++); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) receiver function,

```
$('div.myClass').attr('id',function(i) { return "id" + i; });
```

Basically id with numeric values are not encouraged, so please prefix the numeric value with some alphabets.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/pZv79/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as given below

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.myClass').attr('id', function (idx) {
        return idx + 1
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TkV45/)

Note: don't forget to include jQuery in your page

Answer (score 0):

You can add id by using of "index()". like below:

```
$('.myClass').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('id',($(this).index()+1));    
});
```